# Equation $\sigma(2z-1)=3z$

Tags: nt.number-theory

While working a special case of `mathoverflow.net/questions/65195`,  I got the equation on the title;
($\sigma(h)$ denotes as usual the sum of all positive divisors of $h$).
Since these question forces more conditions, namely: $z$ odd, $3$ divides $2z-1$ and $2z-1$ should be a square;
I was able to check up to about $18 \cdot 10^{10}$ for $z$  the inexistence of such $z$.

But the equation on the title have some solutions anyway if we forget the condition $z$ odd:

namely:

$$
8,104,512,1488,9680,73728,603680, \ldots
$$

Question:

Are all solutions $z$ of the equation

$$
\sigma(2z-1) =3z
$$

even numbers ???

EDIT: My allowed computer time is already used for other stuff. Would be nice if by chance somebody can help
to find more solutions.  I know only of the next solution
$$
z = 2508800
$$
than can be reached relatively quickly (do not need a "batch" job on a server).

Comment: Sequence seems to be related to http://oeis.org/A063906

Comment: "feedback" sure.